# Running a exe file is blocked on my Windows machine. Looking for workaround

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript based Protractor automation setup. I'm almost sure that running an exe file through the code is blocked somehow. But I can run it on cmd manually and it works. I don't see any error on the console while running (I use VS Code) But is does't perform what it supposed to. 
Below is my code which is very simple:

```
var exec=require('child_process').execFile;  //Also tried: require('shelljs');
exec('./support/abc.exe');
```

Is there a way to bypass the firewall or the service whichever is responsible and run exe from my JavaScript code?

Comment: `I don't see any error on the console while running` then what has given you the impression that this is the issue you're facing?

Comment: I executed on cmd and it does what it supposed to. Problem only when I execute it from my JS code.

Comment: Sure, but why are you convinced it's a permissions issue and not that your code is written incorrectly? Wrong code doesn't necessarily produce an error, and without a [mcve] it will be nearly impossible for anyone on Stack Overflow to help you without guessing at what your actual problem is.

Comment: If you can run the exe via command line, and you can run JavaScript via VSC, I seriously doubt there is some amazing firewall that can detect that your code (ran with your user permissions) is trying to call the exe and specifically block that. More likely is the code isn't quite right... like defining `var exe=...` and calling `exec()`.

Comment: Is it a typo  where the code uses `exec` instead of `exe`?

Comment: How are you using VS Code to run that code? You should run the nodejs script in the console in the same manner as you'd otherwise run the exe directly.

Comment: Does protractor run under the same user and permissions as running the files manually?

Comment: That is a typo here. Sorry about that. I have corrected my question. Here I go again. I have an exe file which contains AutoIT script in it. AutoIT is a program to automate user actions on Windows platform. I can compile the script and make it an exe and want to run through my JS code. When I run it on cmd with regular user permission, it runs perfectly well. But when i run it using above code it doesn't. I open VS Code with the same user permissions. I've also heard from my colleague that running an exe is blocked for security reasons. But I'm not sure how that is implemented. Though not sure

Comment: I'm not sure about the blocking thing. So looking for reason why it doesn't work and what the solution to it.

Comment: I have fixed it myself. Issue was actually not the above code but the one before to it. Sorry I didn't give complete code as I believed the cause is this line. That was the wrong guess. I appreciate your time and suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out lately that nothing actually blocks the exe file. My code before this line had the problem. I fixed the issue and it's now working fine. Thanks to people who spent time looking into my question and gave valuable suggestion.

Comment: Can you write how you fixed your issue in your answer so people that find this question can easily see the fix ?